# Setting NIC speed and duplex mode on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, duplex, nic

I am looking for a way to set the speed and duplex mode of a network adapter on Windows using C/C++ APIs. I have looked into Ip Helper, WMI and SetupDI without any luck.
Another approach involved editing registry values, however this seems to be vendor-specific.

In a nutshell, I am looking for a solution which works on all NICs and could be applied dynamically (no reboot needed). Is there any way to achieve this goal?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out by setting the following registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\xxxx\*SpeedDuplex

which seems to be standardized at least since Windows Server 2003 (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780532(v=ws.10).aspx).

I then disable/enable the network adapter using the Shell Network Interface method described here: http://www.gershnik.com/faq/manage.asp#enable